# how to change height of div to covered the text area (CSS)

Tags: css, width

Orginal CSS Code
http://www.faressoft.org/BlueCristalTheme/postView.php

[image]

Result should be

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few things going on here:

- your comment box div has a fixed height of 100px
- all the elements inside this div are absolutely positioned, which takes them out of the normal flow of the document, which results in the containing comment box div not able to wrap / stretch to fit around the children
- use floats or just remove the positioning for the larger content which looks like the second `<p>`. use margins to position this `<p>`, see below

I was able to fix the problem by changing your CSS as follows:

```
#comments .commentBox { /* style.css line 483 */
background-color:#DCDCDC;
/*height:100px; --removed this */
min-height:100px;
position:relative;
}

#comments .commentBox .comment-content { /* style.css line 523 */
color:#676767;
font-size:0.91em;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:24px;
margin:52px 92px 0 0; /* -- added this */
/* -- removed these
position:absolute;
right:95px;
top:52px;
width:570px;
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the clearfix hack.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}
```

Then, add `class="clearfix"` to your div (or `clearfix` to your existing div class), and it should clear that text properly.

Comment: there's no floats being used there, the clearfix hack is not going to help in this case.

Comment: @Moin Zaman, AFAIK, absolutely positioned elements are out the flow, then I think that clearfix should works too.

Comment: @Jesus: Nope, the clearfix hack is only for floating elements. Also it has it's issues. read: http://thinkvitamin.com/design/everything-you-know-about-clearfix-is-wrong/ and http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/05/lessons-learned-concerning-the-clearfix-css-hack/

Comment: @Moin Zaman Ah, my mistake. For some reason my brain decided he was using floats. :)